# How to Add a text label for 3D vertice in Three.Js

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, three.js

I want to Add a label text for a particular point in a 3D plane drawn using Three.js 
Please Give me some idea on how to proceed in this as i am new to three.js

I had tried using the following code, but it did not really worked for me to add a label text exactly on the vertices.

```
    var spritey = makeTextSprite(" Hello, ",
        { fontsize: 10, borderColor: { r: 255, g: 0, b: 0, a: 1.0 }, backgroundColor: { r: 255, g: 100, b: 100, a: 0.8 } });
    spritey.position.set(10, 20, 30);
    scene.add(spritey);

    var spritey = makeTextSprite(" World! ",-1,1,.25,
        { fontsize: 10, fontface: "Georgia", borderColor: { r: 0, g: 0, b: 255, a: 1.0 } });
    spritey.position.set(10, 20, 10);
    scene.add(spritey);
```

I want to add text label for the following points:(x,y,z)

(10,20,30) (10,20,10) (30,20,10) (30,20,30)

Comment: do you mean the coordinates you wrote are not precise enough ? (have you got a link ?)

Comment: @Astrak No I have to give some label along with the co ordinates something like Channel 1 (10,20,30)

Comment: I had found some solution, but the text is coming in 3d effects. I have added the jsfiddle link. http://jsfiddle.net/VsWb9/3813/  Please help me in removing the shadow of text. and normal style.

Comment: add `height:0` in the parameters